How to specify [[hints.enabled]] Alacritty section one matching hypelinks (open on mac) and second any file paths and open in vim
I am using Alacritty terminal for quite some time and it has a great feature to follow hyperlinks when clicking Ctrl+Shift+U. I am using MAC so a default program is open.
Iam trying to add one more section
[[hints.enabled]]
command = "vim" # On Linux/BSD
# command = "open" # On macOS
# command = { program = "cmd", args = [ "/c", "start", "" ] } # On Windows
hyperlinks = false
post_processing = true
persist = false
mouse.enabled = true
binding = { key = "F", mods = "Control|Shift" }
regex = '(\n|.)*/\.[^/]*[^~]'

The goal would be pretty straightforward. If Alacritty finds on a current focused terminal
paths like lines below, I would like to follow them with vim.
~/path/to/file.(whatever suffix)
../path/to/file.(whatever suffix)
path/to/file.(whatever suffix)

Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git restore <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
        modified:   .terraform.lock.hcl
        modified:   main.tf
...
etc
...

Any ideas ?
Thx

So, I have tried your suggestion, but it feels like I can not open it in vim
    [[hints.enabled]]
command = "vim" # On Linux/BSD
hyperlinks = false
post_processing = true
persist = false
mouse.enabled = true
binding = { key = "F", mods = "Control|Shift" }
regex = '.*/[^/]+\.[[:alnum:]]+'

It simply does nothing

It does matching, so I can see letters, but nothing happens when I hit a letter.

[26802.848719500s] [WARN ] [alacritty] Unable to launch nvim with args ["        file/path.yaml"]
Edit: I see that in tour case, you do not have this square brackets [".."] with the argument inside. In my case, the file that is matched, is always in this weird square brackets

Another problem is that regexp is matching not only filepaht but also everything from the beginng of the line

Regexp now works much better, but I still get this error:
[WARN ] [alacritty] Unable to launch nvim with args ["organization/projects/file.yaml"]

Perhaps nvim is not found in your PATH. If you type command -v nvim in the terminal shell and it says, for example, /usr/bin/nvim, then try using that full name instead of just "nvim". But if the PATH is not right, there may be other things in the environment that are not right.

YEs, you are right .. this will be MAC specific.
Do you know by any change how to "prepend" $PWD,
cause if I am e.g. /some/path and file that is matched is just file.yaml nvim or any other program does not know the full path e.g  command = {program = "open", args=["$PWD/"]} 
However,  I would need to join arguments then

I've moved my comments into an answer, which you can accept by clicking on the tick mark if you think it answers your question. For your last comment please start a new post, so others might answer too. It is best to handle one problem per post.

If you just want a regex to match the first 3 lines in your example, then
something like
regex = '[^ ]*/[^/]+\.[[:alnum:]]+'


might do. It matches anything not including spaces ending with / followed
by any chars not /, then a dot, and any alpha-numeric. ("+" means at least 1). Your regex is just missing something before the \. to match the final "file" part.
To see what happens when you type Ctrl Shift F,
start alacritty from another terminal with option -vv so you can see
the debug output. It highlights each match with a letter from the configured
"alphabet", by default j then f and so on.
When you hit the letter you should see the debug output:
[DEBUG] [alacritty] Launched vim with args ["~/path/to/file.abc"]

The debug shows that the args to vim is an array, even though there is
only 1 entry in the array.

I am getting the same results, but the main problem is that a file is not getting created in Alacitty even though I see the same debug message [DEBUG] [alacritty] Launched vim with args ["~/path/to/some/file.yaml"]

I don't know enough about MacOS to know what it does when running programs from the terminal. For example, in Linux X11 it needs the environment variable DISPLAY to be set, or in Wayland WAYLAND_DISPLAY, and so on. There is a specific macos stackexchange site you might try. Perhaps you can get open to run vim, example question?
